# Relative Path issue while using PHP Include in subdirectories

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am in the process of building a PHP application. The application itself has large number of pages and hence I decided to categorize each files into corresponding subdirectories.

However I have encountered a problem. All the template resources folders(CSS, JS, Images, etc.) are located in the root folder `localhost/appname/`, and also the Navigation Menu (`navmenu.php`). I am including the menu in each page.

**The problem arises when I try to include the `navmenu.php` inside the files in sub-directories.**

For example, when I include `navmenu.php` in `index.php` (both in root folder), it works great. But when I include `navmenu.php` in addstudent.php located in the student subdirectory, all the `<a href>` links in navmenu.php become student/*.php (Relative Links)

What is the proper way to solve such situations?

I have a configuration file which is included in all PHP files. How should I create a constant, and how should I update the links in the `navmenu.php` href links?

Comment: please explain the structure of directory once (folder hierarchy)

Comment: Ignore my duplicate flag, php prob does suit better here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For it to always be included no matter the directory depth try the following

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/navmenu.php";
```

This should return something like: `/home/<user>/public_html/includes/navmenu.php`

In majority of my projects; I have a settings file similar too:

```
$LiveDir = "http://localhost/project";
$RootDir = "/home/user/public_html/project";
```

This is primarily beneficial when changing hostname, as you only have to change the links in one file rather than going through ALL your pages and updating the links

```
<a href='<?=$LiveDir?>/some/directory/index.php'>Some Link</a>
```

I use a similar setup to work between my work and my home on a huge CRM. If I am at home links get prefixed with `http://127.0.0.1/` when I'm at work it automatically converts to `http://192.168.10.23/Matilda`

> Caution: **$_SERVER** does not get populated during a cron job. A work around:

Create a file: `CronMgr.php` (for example) with the contents and direct your cron job to it.:

```
<?php file_get_contents("/full/path/to/the/script.php"); ?>
```

This will open an instance where `$_SERVER` **is** populated and the script will run without issue.

Answer (score 0):

In this sort of situation I would define a constant that holds the project root's directory path and you include everything relative to that. This lets you avoid doing relative path includes.

e.g. Make sure this gets loaded for all pages. e.g. a general conf file or general index.php. I don't know how you have things set up. (Or use the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` as pointed out elsewhere)

```
define('PROJECT_ROOT','/localhost/appname/');
```

and then somewhere else

```
include(PROJECT_ROOT . 'navmenu.php');
```

Comment: `Warning: include(localhost/squad/manager/navmenu.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory `

Note : I'm using Wampserver. 
Folder Structure : c:\>wamp\www\squad\manager\

Comment: Use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` your include path SHOULD be `c:\wamp\www\squad\manager\navmenu.php` See my answer

Comment: @user3765203 Well you obviously have to replace what I put with your full path. You're original question stated that your file path "localhost/appname/" So that's what I used.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior of browsers.
To solve your problem there are 2 ways:
1. Start links with '/', i.e. '/index.php', '/about.php' etc. This makes browser create url from root of web-site.
2. Write complete paths to pages in navmenu.php with PHP:

```
$rootPath = 'http://example.com/';
<a href="<?php echo $rootPath; ?>">Home</a>
<a href="<?php echo $rootPath.'/about.php'; ?>">About</a>
```

Comment: Alternatively `<a href='../../../../../../../about.php'>` you can travel back as far as you want using `../../` until it hits the root directory, any additional traverses beyond the root directory are ignored.